# KendoUI, can you call C# methods within ClientTemplate() with Parameter from Model

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

// would like to access Id value not the string being passed, so I expect 1 in my method not "#: Id #"

```
.ClientTemplate(ABFront.Model.MethodTest("#: Id #"));


Kendo()
.Grid<Model>()
.Name("AB")
.Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Bound(p => p.ID);
   columns.Bound(p => p.Name)
.ClientTemplate(ABFront.Model.MethodTest("#: Id #"));
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Read(read => read.Action("ReadPeople", "Person"))
)
```

Comment: The call of `ABFront.Model.MethodTest()` is done when the page is rendered on the server. `"#: Id #"` is executed when Kendo UI (so JavaScript) creates your grid. So there is no way, your method could get the id. What is `ABFront.Model.MethodTest()` supposed to do?

Comment: The `ClientTemplate` function is used only to call JavaScript functions and hence C# functions cannot be called. Rather than trying to call a ClientTemplate, Create a new Property 'NewId'  and set it using `MethodTest` and then use it in following way `columns.Bound(p => p.NewId);`